# Understanding my shapefile's coordinate points (not lat/lon) and why spatial joins own't work

Tags: python, gis, polygon, postgis, shapefile

I downloaded a shapefile of [Postal Codes in Mexico City here](https://datos.gob.mx/busca/dataset/ubicacion-de-codigos-postales-en-mexico/resource/fba3f792-cb83-42da-94eb-36d3befd0d66).

I'm trying to do a spatial join to see which zip codes intersect with a particular zone I'm interested in.

But when I load the postal codes:

```
codigos = gpd.read_file('/Users/jaehakyu/Documents/Shapefiles/Mexico Postal Codes/CP_CdMx/CP_09CDMX_v4.shp')
codigos.head()
```

I notice strange output in the polygons for these postal codes. They're not comprised of lat/lon coordinates. Instead, they look like this:

> POLYGON ((2794650.259300001 819469.0967999995, 2794601.180299997 819320.3825999983, 2794595.038099997 819303.2646000013, 2794581.846100003 819266.4985000007, 2794552.451700002 819177.5449000001, 2794539.257799998 819142.9415000007, 2794490.202399999 819013.9316000007, 2794461.8829 819006.0326999985, 2794333.362800002 818970.185899999, 2794287.639799997 818974.6688000001, 2794223.908 818980.9173000008, 2794210.812299997 818904.4486999999, 2794187.823399998 818901.436999999, 2794164.019500002 818896.5203000009, 2794128.538500004 818896.0044, 2794122.643299997 818895.9186999984, 2794077.665700004 818894.2122999988, 2794066.248400003 818891.7342999987, 2794046.369499996 818886.5003999993, 2794006.863200001 818880.5144000016, 2793988.908100002 818882.2074999996, 2793965.905199997 818887.1242000014, 2793955.3869 818892.3366999999, 2793903.004799999 818932.752799999, 2793796.985100001 818913.691399999, 2793741.294 818906.6301999986, 2793596.247299999 818889.4554999992, 2793571.957000002 819033.999499999, 2793552.235299997 819034.7226999998, 2793527.926200002 819036.2868999988, 2793444.091899998 818973.02, 2793442.978699997 819118.5722999983, 2793437.997699998 819133.6957999989, 2793430.251699999 819144.4745000005, 2793414.9217 819147.9660999998, 2793334.550800003 819163.0062999986, 2793290.008699998 819170.9169000015, 2793213.590499997 819263.4613000005, 2793110.11 819265.5681000017, 2793117.498800002 819308.4505000003, 2793146.486199997 819475.7197000012, 2793186.218999997 819462.5135999992, 2793249.972900003 819441.3235000001, 2793345.965300001 819414.0322999991, 2793436.257799998 819398.3966999985, 2793517.804700002 819384.2754999995, 2793565.4133 819377.8266999982, 2793601.6972 819374.2901000008, 2793787.7729 819356.7437000014, 2793841.170500003 819343.5784999989, 2793848.679399997 819336.9222000018, 2793862.701300003 819415.7888999991, 2793896.867299996 819558.6755999997, 2793912.430100001 819623.6581000015, 2793934.3768 819672.3953000009, 2793959.285499997 819765.1700000018, 2793964.056900002 819787.6761000007, 2793984.413400002 819883.6871000007, 2793997.486699998 819948.0406999998, 2794004.954099998 819981.5982000008, 2794111.821699999 819973.7314999998, 2794230.936700001 819964.9633999988, 2794347.152999997 819955.9384000003, 2794343.185599998 819899.5188000016, 2794458.9071 819890.1013999991, 2794764.265699998 819868.1314000003, 2794762.4494 819852.9858999997, 2794736.8922 819766.9114000015, 2794727.679099999 819735.4631999992, 2794672.272100002 819545.7978999987, 2794650.259300001 819469.0967999995))

I tried doing a spatial join anyway, but no luck. I've also tried mapping these polygons using CartoDB, but they do not show up. I'm not sure what I'm dealing with and would love some help understanding:

(1) What the coordinate points here are.
(2) How to get them to lat/lon so that a spatial join can work

Thank you! I am working on this using geopandas and shapely in Python, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it goes without saying, but to spatially join two datasets they need to be in the same coordinate system. Latitude/longitude are coordinates in some geographic coordinate system (and there is more than one, so make sure you know which!).

Shapefiles can include coordinates in a variety of coordinate systems. Typically there is a `.prj` file that is distributed with the shapefile that describes the coordinate system information.

Looking at your data, I'd guess that it's in eastings and northings, measured in meters, in some projected coordinate system. So before you can spatially join with data in a geographic coordinate system you will first need to *unproject* the data (go from a projected or planar coordinate system to a spheroidal one), and then possibly perform a *datum shift* (adjust for differences between different geographic coordinate systems).

I don't know about geopandas or shapely, but I know the `proj4` library has good Python bindings and can perform these operations. But either way you'll need the data in the `.prj` file.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing:

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Trying to read up more about it now, but generally very new to geospatial data and would love any pointers you may have! Thank you!